# Aggregate an array in a document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregate

I have a voting app and I have a mongoose scheme as follows:

```
var optionSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    option:{type:String,required:true},
    count:{type:Number,required:true}
});

var pollSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    creator:{type:String,required:true},
    title:{type:String,required:true},
    options:[optionSchema]
});
```

I am trying to figure out if I can pull the top X documents by the aggregate count of all the options for each document in node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
db.polls.aggregate([
    {
         $project: {
            totalOptionCount: { $sum: "$options.count"}
        },
    },
    { $sort : { totalOptionCount : 1 }},
    { $limit : 5 }
])
```

Comment: This is perfect.  The only change I had to make was after sort I needed to take the $ off of the totalOptionCount.

Comment: Took me too much time to format the answer without an editor XD

Can you accept my answer then?

Comment: My apologies I thought I clicked it, that's what I get for using the mobile site